# How to Bring One's Own Model to MindsDB?

Tags: tensorflow, mindsdb

I have some data in my MySQL database that I want to make predictions on. Now, I also have a model developed using TensorFlow on similar data to make these predictions.

I want to use the power of in-database machine learning in order to make my predictions. I am thinking of using MindsDB for this purpose.

I have already used MindsDB for another use case, where I trained the model on the data in my database and then subsequently used it for making predictions. But, is it possible to use my pre-developed model in order to make predictions? If so, how do I do it?

Some example code would be greatly appreciated.